# Convert txt file to adjacency list

Tags: c

```
S,John 2 MATH101 CSE100
K,Jack 2 BLAW203 MATH101 
B,Brown 2 STAT253 MATH259 
G,Mary 3 MATH259 HIST111 STAT253
```

This is my txt file and I want to convert adjancency list.

The courses in the matrix are named as numbers, like the following:

```
0 - MATH101 
1 - CSE100 
2 - BLAW203 
3 - STAT253 
4 - MATH259 
5 - HIST111
```

How can I read and convert adjancency list in C ? Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried it yet?  Come back when you have an attempt

Comment: I have no idea.It is part of my project.If I can do this part , I will complete project.

Comment: We aren't here to do your homework, you have to bring something to the table.   Look at the problem very high-level (not in terms of programming, just as a concept in general).  See if you can work it down from high-level to code.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is the parsing part - now make a list using structs and check for already inserted elements.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main()
{ 

    FILE *in = fopen("newfile","r");
    FILE *out = fopen("newfile2.txt","w");
    size_t snby = 1024;
    char *lineBuf = malloc(1024*sizeof(char));
    char *tmpVal;
    char *maxVal;
    int loop = 0;
    int gar = 0;
    int line = 0;
    while(getline(&lineBuf, &snby, in) != -1)
    { 
            if (gar == 0)
            {
                fprintf(out, "%d - ", line);
                line++;
                gar++;
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(out, "\n%d - ", line);
                line++;
            }
            line++;
            int mark = 0;
            tmpVal = lineBuf;
            while(mark != 2)
            {
                if (*tmpVal == ' ') mark++;
                tmpVal++;
            }
            while(*tmpVal != '\n')
            {
                if(*tmpVal == ' ')
                {
                    fprintf(out, "\n%d - ", line);
                    line++;
                }
                else
                {
                    fprintf(out, "%c", *tmpVal);
                }
                tmpVal++;
            }


    }
    free(lineBuf); 
    fclose(out);
    fclose(in);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way it can be done:

1. Open the input file. in READ mode.
2. Enter a loop to read all lines from the input file.
  1. Read the first line from the file.
  2. Allocate a new student list node.
  3. Parse the student name from the lineBuf fields to newStudentNode->name
  4. Parse the number of courses from lineBuf.
  5. Enter a loop to parse each course name from the lineBuf.
    1. Parse a course name.
    2. Convert the course name to a course number.
    3. Allocate a new course node.
    4. Insert the newCourseNode as the tail node of the newStudentNode's courseList.
  6. Insert the newStudentNode as the tail node of the studentList.

And if needed, [here](http://www.mahonri.info/SO/23765663_convert-txt-file-to-adjacency-list.c) is the spoiler code.